# IIS7.5 How to make a binding for 2 domains, 2 IPs and 2 certificates

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, certificate, iis-7.5, bindings

I am clutching at straws... hope you can help me with this old server.

I want to bind domain1.com to ip 123.456.7.1 and domain2.com to 123.456.7.2, each with its own certificate. As longs as I configure it for http, there's no issue. My bindings look like this:

```
          type   hostname       port    ip
site2 ->  http   domain1.com    80      123.456.7.1
site2 ->  http   domain2.com    80      123.456.7.2
```

But I want to bind a certificate to each site. I use the Certify-the-web installer to do this for me. This results in:

```
          type   hostname       port    ip
site1 ->  http   domain1.com    80      123.456.7.1
          https  domain1.com    443     123.456.7.1

site2 ->  http   domain2.com    80      123.456.7.2
          https  domain2.com    443     123.456.7.2
```

Which works fine for domain1, but gives a wrong certificate warning for domain2 (according to Chrome and Firefox it uses the cert of domain1). It has the right certificate selected  in both https bindings when I inspect them. I did restart each site in IIS.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use Windows Server 2008R2. It's End Of Life. Upgrade to supported software.

Comment: Inspect the output of `netsh http show sslcert`. Does it show different certs for the two sites?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Yes, I do have two sites under the same application id, dunno if that's a problem. Both entries are the same except for ip and cert hash.

Comment: Your setup should work, hard to figure out why it doesn't. I would delete the sites and start over from scratch.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Alright, it's good to know that I didn't go in the wrong direction. Hard to find good instructions. Thanks!